# Dynamically Creating bootstrap-sliders with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying this with no success. For reference, the bootstrap slider is here : http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/.

I'm not a javascript expert, either, so this might be very simple. The `bootstrap-slider` site has many examples of how to configure the sliders the way you want them. I'm going to have many sliders generated depending on how many objects are pulled from a JSON file or some other data storing method. It could be 2 or it could be 20.

I created a javascript function called createSlider that I've attempted to pass all of the information required at the `bootstrap-slider` site. I'm not getting any errors in my Chrome debugging area, but nothing is happening. All of the appropriate client-side sources are loading.

```
function createSlider (orgId) {
slidersList = document.getElementById('slidersList');
element = slidersList.createElement("div");
var sliderElement = element.createElement('input');

var sliderUnique= orgId.concat("Slider");
var sliderUniqueVal = orgId.concat("SliderVal");
sliderElement.setAttribute('id', charityId);
sliderElement.setAttribute('data-slider-id', sliderUnique);
sliderElement.setAttribute('type', 'text');
sliderElement.setAttribute('data-slider-min', '0');
sliderElement.setAttribute('data-slider-max', '100');
sliderElement.setAttribute('data-slider-step', '1');
sliderElement.setAttribute('data-slider-value', '50');

var span = element.createElement('span');
span.setAttribute('style', 'padding-left:5px;');
span.innerHTML =' ';

var innerSpan = span.createElement('span');
innerSpan.setAttribute('id', sliderUniqueVal);
innerSpan.innerHTML = '50';

sliderElement.slider({tooltip: 'hide'});
sliderElement.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    innerSpan.innerHTML = text(slideEvt.value);
});

}
```

The `slider()` function is from the external site, and runs fine if I explicitly call it like the examples state to. Anyone know what's going wrong? Is there a better way to do this? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, in plain JavaScript, you can only use `document.createElement` and then append to another HTML element. You cannot call `createElement` directly against another HTML element.

I changed some of what you wrote from plain old JavaScript into JQuery, and now seems to work:

P.S. Didn't know where charityId came from, so just added it as another parameter into the function.

```js
$(function() {
    createSlider('o1','c1');
    createSlider('o2','c2');
    createSlider('o3','c3');
});

function createSlider (orgId, charityId) {
    var slidersList = $('#slidersList');
    var element = $("<div></div>").appendTo(slidersList);
    var sliderElement = $("<input/>").appendTo(element);

    var sliderUnique= orgId.concat("Slider");
    var sliderUniqueVal = orgId.concat("SliderVal");
    sliderElement.attr('id', charityId);
    sliderElement.attr('data-slider-id', sliderUnique);
    sliderElement.attr('type', 'text');
    sliderElement.attr('data-slider-min', '0');
    sliderElement.attr('data-slider-max', '100');
    sliderElement.attr('data-slider-step', '1');
    sliderElement.attr('data-slider-value', '50');

    var span = $('<span></span>').appendTo(element);
    span.attr('style', 'padding-left:5px;');
    span.html(' ');

    var innerSpan = $('<span></span>').appendTo(span);
    innerSpan.attr('id', sliderUniqueVal);
    innerSpan.html('50');

    sliderElement.slider({tooltip: 'hide'});
    
    sliderElement.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
           innerSpan.text(slideEvt.value);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/stylesheets/bootstrap-slider.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://seiyria.github.io/bootstrap-slider/javascripts/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<div id="slidersList"></div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. I didn't know I couldn't use javascript alone- jquery is working fine.