# How to remove element according to condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 attribute for my images are `data-web-src`,`data-tablet-src` and `data-mobil-src` and I'm using theese attribute for responsive.If my images has no data-mobile-src attribute than remove this image on mobile or tablet or for web.. and it's work but as your see below example..I just only want to do this in `.slider` images how can I do that ?

```js
function noLazyImages(e) {
  $(e + '.lazy_res').attr('src', function(_, oldSrc) {
    var elData = $(this).data(),
      winWidth = $(window).width();
    if (winWidth < 768 && winWidth >= 480) {
      if (elData['tabletSrc']) {
        return elData['tabletSrc'];
      }
    } else if (winWidth < 480) {
      if (elData['mobilSrc']) {
        return elData['mobilSrc'];
      }
    }
    return elData['webSrc'];
  });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  noLazyImages("body img");
});
noLazyImages("body img");
```

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-mobil-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/b1e10f433e404191bb78123f5188dc56.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"/>

<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"/>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="item">
  <a href="#"><img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-mobil-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/b1e10f433e404191bb78123f5188dc56.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"/>
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  <a href="#"><img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/dRXKbW)

Comment: Use the picture element with multiple source elements. You won't need to reinvent the wheel that way.

Comment: but picture element is not working with old browser ://

Comment: Use the picturefill polyfill that's available.

Comment: First you have to make and load your image tags, then create a slider . Use sliderjs to make a responsive slider: http://www.slidesjs.com

Comment: I don't need another slider for that and I guess it can handle with jquery

Comment: @ani_css are u useing a framework ,like bootstrap , or materialize!?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap :)

Comment: @ani_css so you need to create slider dynamically by javascript: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109478/dynamically-creating-bootstrap-sliders-with-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: I guess you don't understan question correctly I just want to hide image if image has no any data-mobil-src attribute on mobil or if has no any data-tablet-src on tablet that's all so why will I recreate slider again? thanks

Answer (score 2):

How about just replacing body with .slider when you call noLazyImages?

Hope this helps.

```js
function noLazyImages(e) {
  $(e + '.lazy_res').attr('src', function(_, oldSrc) {
    var elData = $(this).data(),
      winWidth = $(window).width();
    if (winWidth < 768 && winWidth >= 480) {
      if (elData['tabletSrc']) {
        return elData['tabletSrc'];
      }
    } else if (winWidth < 480) {
      if (elData['mobilSrc']) {
        return elData['mobilSrc'];
      }
    }
    return elData['webSrc'];
  });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
  noLazyImages(".slider img");
});
noLazyImages(".slider img");
```

```css
img {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-mobil-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/b1e10f433e404191bb78123f5188dc56.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"/>

<img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"/>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="item">
  <a href="#"><img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-mobil-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/b1e10f433e404191bb78123f5188dc56.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"/>
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  <a href="#"><img class="lazy_res" data-web-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/0d2af672b40c4d9ebf113a1784c33a7f.png" data-tablet-src="https://image.prntscr.com/image/a9fb88455946432890b27a946e99d387.png"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you I tried this way but I guess it's not going to responsive another images which is not inside `.slider` and so is there any way to remove image ? if image has no attribute

Comment: You asked "I just only want to do this in .slider images how can I do that ?" and I answered your question. Perhaps you need to tune your jquery function and play around with it.

Comment: I mean if my any image has no `data-mobil-src` or `data-tablet-src` then don't show theese image or mobile or on tablet do this only for .slider anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Analyzing if in your *var elData = $(this).data()* -> elData object those properties exists (*hasOwnProperty* in js ) can be a good way to achieve your desired results.